# OData v2: Correct Encoding Issue with StructuredQuery Class for DateTimeOffset in SAPQuery

Tags: java, http, odata, encode, sap-gateway

I'm encountering an issue with the StructuredQuery class in OData v2 when attempting to encode DateTimeOffset values for a GET request to API_BATCH_SRV/BATCH. It does not encode the '+' sign. Despite trying withCustomParameter to manually encode the '+' in DateTimeOffset values to '%2B', it results in '%252B' encoding, causing the HTTP request to fail. Is there a workaround or solution to ensure proper encoding for DateTimeOffset values in this context?